# Is this system linear or non linear? $y[n]=cos(\frac{5\pi}{8}*n+\frac{\pi}{4})$

Tags: linear-systems

$y[n]=cos(\frac{5\pi}{8}*n+\frac{\pi}{4})$

If I let $(\frac{5\pi}{8}*n+\frac{\pi}{4})=x[n]$, I get the system as non linear. But one of my teacher says it is linear, whereas another teacher says it is non linear.

Comment: systems are classified as *"linear"* or *"nonlinear"*.  not signals.  signals are what they are.

Comment: Oh so is it linear system or non linear system? Thanks for the input tho.

Comment: there is no system.  it's a signal.

Comment: So the system's output is always the same, regardless of the input? There's no $x[n]$ in your equation ...

Comment: Oh makes sense @MattL. Question might be wrong. Or they might have intended x(n) instead of n.

Comment: Yes, check that. Otherwise, a system with an output that's independent of the input can't be linear.

Comment: One of my teacher told me to multiply the given signal by dirac delta function $\delta(n)$ What do you think about that? If we do that then it still will come non linear tbh.

Comment: @MattL. What about a system that maps everything to 0 ... ;-).

Comment: @bikramnepali You still have not posed a clear question. In fact, as written, your question does not make any sense. You've provided a signal and did not make clear what the relation between the signal and the system is supposed to be.

Comment: Your equation describes a signal, not a system. That means the question is non-sensical, linearity isn't defined for signals. Check your course materials.  This is VERY important to understand. If your teachers can't get this straight, I'd worry about the quality of the course., but chances are you got confused somewhere.

Comment: @Hilmar It was a sequence not signal neither system. Sorry for the mistake. Do you know the way now?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac It was neither signal nor system but a sequence. Can it be solved now?

Comment: @bikramnepali in the context of discrete-time signal processing sequences and signals are the same thing. Show the original question with all the information given to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is
$$
x[n] = (\frac{5\pi}{8}*n+\frac{\pi}{4}).
$$
Then the system is $y[n]=cos(x[n])$, which is a non-linear system.

If the input is
$$
x[n]=cos(\frac{5\pi}{8}*n+\frac{\pi}{4}).
$$
Then the system is $y[n] = x[n]$, which is a linear system.

A key criteria to judge if a system is linear or non-linear is to determine if the system is linear additive or not. Which means, if the input signal is sum of two or more sub-input-signals, and the output signal is the sum of the sub-output-signals that is driven by each sub-input-signal individually. Using Math language, a linear system must has the characteristic as below:
Suppose
$$
y_1[n] = f(x_1[n]),
y_2[n] = f(x_2[n]),
$$
then for a linear system,
$$
y_1[n]+y_2[n]=f(x_1[n])+f(x_2[n])=f(x_1[n]+x_2[n])
$$
which means, if
$x[n] = x_1[n]+x_2[n]$, then $y[n]=f(x[n])=y_1[n]+y_2[n]$.